# How to open a specific fragment page in viewpager from another activity button click event

Tags: android

Could any one let me know how to open a specific fragment present in a 
viewpager from another activities button click event.

I am using a alert dialog which shows two options
to select respective screens in viewpager like below but I am getting null 
pointer on clicking screentwo button which has code to open viewpagers second page.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    int pos;
    ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
         pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
      Button   ds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_back);
     ds.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(goIntent);

        }
     });
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

            case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
            default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }       
    }

goesBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_front);
goesBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please choose your Favourite Screen");
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("ScreenOne",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent go = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(go);
             }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ScreenTwo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // Create new fragment and transaction
                SecondFragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, "NewFragment");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
             }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();         
    }
});
```

Thanks & Regards,

Aditya.J

Comment: Try `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int index);`

Comment: Hello  activesince93, thank you for your fast reply, I am really don't know where to keep this code.Should I keep it in the alert dialog's positive button click event.I mean I am not getting the viewpager's object in secondactivity.Please help!

Comment: as activesince93, suggested Pass the page number you want to show on the view pager activity and set the pages accordingly in the onCreate() method of the activity.

Comment: Hello Sanjeet, thanks for your reply.Actually I am using intent to open second activity like this way via button click from main activity.Button   ds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_back);
  ds.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent goIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(goIntent);
      
   }
  });
So as you said should I put extra the viewpager's page position ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your onClick just pass the position of viewpager you want to show in the intent's extras, and in the viewpager activity just call `pager.setCurrentItem(position)`.

So code would be something like this for your onClick

```
goesBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_front);
goesBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Please choose your Favourite Screen");
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("ScreenOne",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent go = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

                // you pass the position you want the viewpager to show in the extra, 
                // please don't forget to define and initialize the position variable
                // properly
                go.putExtra("viewpager_position", 0)

                startActivity(go);
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ScreenTwo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // Create new fragment and transaction

                /*SecondFragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, "NewFragment");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();*/
                // You don't do the above code, it will just create a new fragment
                // you do this instead.
                Intent go = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

                // you pass the position you want the viewpager to show in the extra, 
                // please don't forget to define and initialize the position variable
                // properly
                go.putExtra("viewpager_position", 1)

                startActivity(go);
             }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();         
    }
});
```

The code for your viewpager activity would be something like this.

```
int pos;
ViewPager pager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    int position = 0;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        position = extras.getInt("viewpager_position");
    }
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
    Button   ds = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_back);
    ds.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent goIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(goIntent);

    }
    });

    pager.setCurrentItem(position) // this way if there is no extras 
    // you will get first position of viewpager
    // otherwise you will get the position of viewpager whichever was passed in the intent.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bhargav.Still I am not getting  what you guys helping me. let me put in this way. Firstly, my app starts with my main activity which has two fragments within viewpager and below this viewpager I kept a button to go to second activity, now in second activity I kept a button with a alert dialog where the user can choose screen one or screen two. for screen one just normal intent call is enought as its my 0 indexed page but when user clicking on second button in alert dialog he should be taken to second fragment i.e. index 1.

Comment: yes so if user selects the 2nd one in the alert dialog, i.e index 1 then just pass the value 1 in the putExtra() like so `go.putExtra("viewpager_position",1)`

Comment: Sure Bhargav, but here my problem is how to get the viewpager's position which actually in my main activity.Should I write a method in my main activity through which I can call the viewpagers second position.

Comment: just pass 0 or 1 for position since its a 0 based index for sectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: Hi Bhargav, I just added my main activity source code on my post. In that main activity class by using a button click I am opening second activity.

Comment: Thank you for your updated code Bhargav, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Bhargav, you resolved my 1 month struggling issue.Thank you very much!:).

Comment: upvote the answer too if it helped you :) it will help me :D

Comment: I already checked marked it as a right answer Bhargav.Thanks again:).

Comment: Hi Bhargav, I have another doubt regarding dynamic view pager pages saving.Could you please help.Here is my post url in stack overflow(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804052/android-viewpager-save-dynamic-pages).

Comment: This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(THE_POSITION)
```

Comment: Someone already given this answer as a comment under OP's post. It's helpful, but what OP would to like to know more is where should this code resides in the logic flow? It will be great if you could complete the answer for OP. Try to improve the answer else chances this will be removed are high as it poses as a low quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will use previous and next buttons to move to previous or next fragments, and it will open up the next activity at the end.

```
 private int[] layouts;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wizard_setup);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));    

        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.fragment_1,
                R.layout.fragment_2,
                R.layout.fragment_3};

        Button btn_next = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
            if (current < layouts.length) {
                // move to next screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } else {
                // open next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(WizardSetupActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Button btn_prev = findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);
        btn_prev.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1;
            if (current >= 0) {
                // move to previous screen
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
            } 
        });
    }
```