# How to start viewpager from given position and then move to second position in the viewpager

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

My design is i have a listview of reports when user click on any report i have to show its detail in the viewpager after this user can swaps viewpager forward or backward to see next and previous report listed in the listview

lets say user clicked on 5th report i showed its detail by getting relevant element associated with the listview item position in the arraylist, now how can i show next report in the viewpager when user swaps forward and previous report when user swaps backward

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627592/7337723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

You have to change position of your viewPager when you swap it left/right.

Comment: You have do position+1 if user swap right and position-1 when user swap left.

You also have to check that position should not be <0 and position should not be > your list size when you swap it left or right.

Comment: then i would have to detect if user swapping left or right?

Comment: Please check this demo it will help you with your current query
https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial